# French physical therapist working in the US?

Tags: usa, france

My boyfriend is a licensed French physical therapist. We want to move to the US (California) but I can't seem to find out if he'd need to redo a degree or get some sort of equivalent in order to work. If anyone has done this before or can send me in the right direction it would be appreciated!

Comment: This https://www.bls.gov/ooh/healthcare/physical-therapists.htm might help

Answer (score 3):

One issue is being allowed to immigrate to the US and work at all. I won't attempt to address that. Another issue is being allowed to work as a physical therapist in California; professions are regulated on a state-by-state basis.

Physical therapists are licensed in California by the [Physical Therapy Board of California](https://www.ptbc.ca.gov/). I would contact them to find out exactly what they require because links from their site about foreign education lead in several directions. One of the organizations involved in this is the [Foreign Credentialing Commission on Physical Therapy](https://www.fccpt.org/). They appear to offer two types of evaluation of foreign education, one type for immigration purposes, and another type for licensure purposes.